# Finding k most common words in a file, using concurrency

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, concurrency, heap, trie

This is an interview question I found.
The first part is to find the `k` most common words in a file. This is a well known question, and the solution can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-k-most-frequent-words-from-a-file/) . The run-time of this solution is `O(nlogk + k)` when `n` is the file size.

Second part is finding the `k` most common words in a file, but this time using concurrency. That means, if we can run `m` thread in parallel in our system - how can we improve the solution above?

This is where I stuck. First I thought of splitting the file to `m` parts and send each part of it to a different thread so he can proccess it. But the problem is that these thread will have to share the same trie, which means they will have to be synchronized. So even if I'll gain better run-time on paper using those `m` threads, in reality I'm pretty sure that using synchronization will make the run-time worse than the run-time in the implementation above.

Do you have an idea how to implement this using concurrency in order to improve the run-time?

Answer (score 1):

This is a map-reduce operation.  Lets say we have a file of length N and M threads:

1. Each thread is assigned a portion of the file, and counts the frequency of all the words in its portion.  This assumes that the threads can access that data in parallel with bounded contention costs:  O(N/M)
2. Each thread hashes the words into M buckets consistently, and sends counts for bucket to the corresponding thread, so that each thread receives counts for a roughly equal portion of the words:  O(N/M)
3. Each thread combines the counts it received to generate total counts of all of its words.  That is combining M results of size O(N/M^2): O(N/M)
4. Each thread calculates its top K counts and sends them to the result processing thread: O(log K * N/M)
5. The result processing thread combines the M sorted lists to extract the top K counts. 
   It's important to ensure that this thread can stop reading an input list when it doesn't need the rest of the data.  Then: O( (K + M) log M )

So with M threads you can do the whole job in O( (N/M) * log K + (K+M) * log M).

If you use a streaming parallel merge for step 5, then you can reduce that to O( (N/M) * log K + K + log M), but that's only better if you have a *lot* of threads.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how exactly each thread receives counts for its words? I didn't understand how this is done with the bucket explanation

Comment: @John if you have M threads, then, for example, each thread number **i** can be in charge of summing up all the counts for all words where **hash(word)%M == i**.  In step (2) each thread distributes the counts for each word from its part of the file to the threads in charge of summing counts for that word.  You can google map-reduce to find out lots more about that

Answer (score 0):

What about letting every thread find the k most common in its share of the file, independently, then merge the results ?

Note that I am pretty skeptical about any speedup possible by performing concurrent reads of the file, which is probably the slowest operation in this problem.

Comment: The merge suggestion won't work. Counter example: say that k=2, we can run 2 threads in parallel and file content is: "w w a a a b b b w w c c c d d d" (pay attention that words are separated by space). We let thread1 to take half of the file ("w w a a a b b b") and thread 2 will take the other half. So in thread1 the two common words will be "a" and "b" and in thread2 the two common words will be "c" and "d". No matter how you choose to merge these results, you won't get "w", which is the most common word.

Comment: @John: well observed, you are quite right. More than k most frequent words must be kept by every thread :-(

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CountMinSketch` to approximately maintain the counts in a compact `O(1)` form. This provides you the heavy hitters without retaining the words. Multiple sketches can be merged together as simple array summations, assuming the identical hash function is used. That allows threads to process independent sections in parallel. It is similar to the hash table approach, except that you have forgotten the word mapping.

The next step would be to scan the dictionary of words to determine the `top k`. If you maintain a dictionary per thread, that could be merged rather than rescanning the file. For each item in that list you query for its frequency, `O(1)`, which lets you rank them to obtain the most popular. As we care about the frequency order, not the words themselves, we reduce `O(lg k)` to `O(lg f)`. In that case words with the same popularity are chained on a list. We can evaluate a new word with the least frequent word in `O(1)` if a `SkipList` or `MinHeap` is used.

The runtime is then the addition of,

- `O(n/T)`, where `n` is the file size and `T` is the number of threads
- `O(T * m)`, where `m` is the number of unique words (cardinality) and `T` threads might produce all `m` words to hash join
- `O(m * lg f)`, where `f` is the top frequencies, to find the most popular words

That results in `O(n/T) + O(T * m) + O(m * lg f)` where `n` is by far the dominant parameter, so it should reduce to `O(n)` in practice.